# Gerar Json x Pesquisa em mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongoose, express.js

Estou gerando um Json.

Mas tenho a seguinte situação:

Possuo um cadastro de contatos que podem pertencer a mesma empresa. 
Ou seja, posso ter duas pessoas cadastradas em uma única empresa.

Como faço para carregar estes contatos em meu json?

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
Contato.findById(contato.Cliente.id,function(err, contatos) {  
             //aqui carrego as informacoes.
```

Porém carrega apenas do último contato cadastrado, e preciso trazer todos.

Comment: O ID no MongoDB é único, sendo assim por Id não tem como achar mais de um, tente usar apenas Contato.find com alguma informação que você tenha.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve buscar pelos contatos que tenham referências aos documentos relacionados.

```
Contato.find({ client_id: client_id }, function(err, contatos) {
// ...
});
```

Ou:

```
Contato.find({ company_id: company_id }, function(err, contatos) {
// ...
});
```